# Run document.ready only if jquery is loaded

Tags: jquery

I have this code in a global JS file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       DoStuff();
 });
```

Unfortunately there are pages that include this file but doesn't include the jquery file. So I get errors:

```
Message: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, 
not a Function object
```

How do I run `document.ready()` only if JQuery file is loaded.

Comment: Is _loaded_ or **not** loaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(window.jQuery) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        DoStuff();
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

Check for `window.jQuery` instead of just `jQuery`. This should circumvent the "not defined" error.

Comment: I get `jQuery is not defined` error. I guess I need to check for if its defined or not.

Comment: @Tejs [I would think not](http://jsfiddle.net/p9KyE/). Of course, the only solution here is if you check `if ('undefined' != typeof(jQuery)){ // your code here }`. Then enclose all the jQuery code inside an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to avoid `$` overrides by other frameworks.

Comment: It all depends on where the script is linked into the lifecycle compared to your script.

Comment: @DotnetDude, please check my update (tested in FF + Firebug only).

Comment: @Tejs Please if you would be so kind explain it to me in code. English is not my native language.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ok, works in IE as well. Can you explain the difference between using the `window` object and not using it?

Comment: @DotnetDude, my previous version doesn't work because, technically, the browser cannot resolve its "base value". See [this](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/) (especially section "What about implicit globals?")

Answer (score 3):

You would test for the existence of jQuery first:

```
 if(jQuery)
 {
     $(document).ready(function() { ... });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 if($){
   // your code here.
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

well, wrap your code inside :

```
if ( $ != undefined && $ != null) {
 //everything here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is loaded, and you're still getting that error, try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        DoStuff();
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

If you meant "**not** loaded", then you can't use the "`ready()`" function.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(jQuery) {  
    $(function() {
        //...
    });
}
```

or

```
if(typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  
    $(function() {
        //...
    });
}
```